# Making a Bar graph with the "mean" score on the "y" axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just a quick background:

I did a study on the effect of vocal music in teaching English. The study had 40 participants including male and female students. it consisted of a control and experimental group. the latter went through a treatment process while the former did not. before the treatment I did a pretest on the subjects to make sure of the homogeneity of the participant's knowledge of English and after the treatment I did a post test to see whether or not the said treatment has had an effect.  What I want to do now is to create a bar graph using R in which the Y axis shows the calculated mean score of the post-test and the X axis the gender.

here's what I did and it did not work:

```
qplot(x = gender, y=mean(Project$posttest_score, data=Project) +geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ditto what @zx8754 said; but there also appears to be a typo in your code. Should `data=Project` be outside of `mean(...)`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to give it a good read!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
ggplot(data=Project, aes(y=posttest_score,x=gender)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, there WAS a typo in the command. Will try you suggestions!